# MySQL - How to group by on two fields and count

Tags: mysql, sql

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `usuarios` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user1` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `user2` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;

INSERT INTO `usuarios` (`id`, `user1`, `user2`) VALUES
(1, 'pepe', NULL),
(2, 'pepe', 'juan'),
(3, 'juan', NULL),
(4, 'juan', NULL),
(5, 'juan', 'pepe'),
(6, NULL, 'pepe'),
(7, 'pepe', 'juan');
```

I need to make a query: I have done this:

```
SELECT
`user1`,
COUNT(`id`) AS Total
FROM usuarios
WHERE (`user1` is not null)
GROUP BY `user1`
UNION
SELECT
`user2`,
COUNT(`id`) AS Total
FROM usuarios
WHERE (`user2` is not null)
GROUP BY `user2`
```

But the result is:

```
user1    total
juan      3
pepe      3
juan      2
pepe      2
```

I need to remove duplicate names, add up the total and this is the result:

```
user1    total
juan      5
pepe      5
```

Comment: SELECT user1, SUM(total) total FROM (your query here) x GROUP BY user1; ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

or, if less code is your thang...

```
SELECT user,COUNT(*) FROM
     (
       SELECT user1 user FROM usuarios
       UNION ALL
       SELECT user2 FROM usuarios
     ) x
 WHERE user IS NOT NULL
 GROUP 
    BY user;
```